# Partition on a Closed Set $A= [2,3]$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Is it possible to define a partition of a closed set, such that the union of the partitions will give $[2,3]$ and their intersection to be empty?

Comment: What properties is your partition supposed to have?

Comment: What's wrong with $[2,2.5)$ and $[2.5,3]$, for example? Or $[2,2.5)$, $\{2.5\}$, and $(2.5,3]$?

Answer (score 2):

You can partition any set $X$ as $X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}$.

Comment: Or as $\{X\}$, for that matter.